# Can an Annotation Callout subtitle be a link that launches safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to add as a subtitle in a Callout Bubble of MKAnnotationPoint a link that launches Safari Browser that eventually goes to that link.Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a button in the bubble, that's why it is designed for?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    annotationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [annotationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = annotationButton;


    return annView;
}
- (void) annotationAction {
//Call a web view here
}
```